# Load multidimensional json file in HTML table

Tags: html, json, multidimensional-array

I had a JSON file loading into an HTML table and now I have a multidimensional json file. I found a dummy JSON file to test it and I made the snippet below. It loads data but it misses some rows in the nest.

```js
//It loads the data from the JSON file 
$(function() {
  
    var data = [{ "name" : "Άντερλεχτ - Σιντ Τρούιντεν(GG/NG)", "outcomes" : [{ "name" : "No goal", "bookie" : "stoiximan", "odds" : 1.91, "stakes" : 53.5279805353 }, { "name" : "Goal", "bookie" : "betrebels", "odds" : 2.2, "stakes" : 46.4720194647 }], "profit" : 2.23844282238 },
    { "name" : "Παρί Σεν Ζερμέν - Μπαρτσελόνα", "outcomes" : [{ "name" : "Παρί Σεν Ζερμέν (1)", "bookie" : "interwetten", "odds" : 4.1, "stakes" : 24.7827486321 }, { "name" : "X", "bookie" : "interwetten", "odds" : 3.5, "stakes" : 29.0312198262 }, { "name" : "Μπαρτσελόνα (2)", "bookie" : "betrebels", "odds" : 2.2, "stakes" : 46.1860315417 }], "profit" : 1.6092693917 }
];
  
var tr;
$.each(data, function(key, val) {
                
$.each(data, function(i, object) {
    $.each(object, function(property, value) {
    tr = $('<tr/>');
    tr.append('<td class="name" rel="' + val.name + '">' + val.name + '</td>');
    tr.append('<td class="bet" rel="' + val.outcomes[i].name + '">' + val.outcomes[i].name + '</td>');
    tr.append('<td class="bookie" rel="' + val.outcomes[i].bookie + '">' + val.outcomes[i].bookie + '</td>');
    tr.append('<td class="metric2" >' + val.outcomes[i].odds + '</td>');
    });
 $('table').append(tr); // moved this here to handle overwriting.
});        
                
  
   });


});
```

```css
h1{
  font-size: 30px;
  color: #fff;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-weight: 300;
  text-align: center;
  margin-bottom: 15px;
}
table{
  width:100%;
  table-layout: fixed;
}
.tbl-header{
  background-color: rgba(255,255,255,0.3);
 }
.tbl-content{
  height:300px;
  overflow-x:auto;
  margin-top: 0px;
}

th{
  padding: 20px 15px;
  text-align: left;
  font-weight: 500;
  font-size: 12px;
  color: #fff;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}
td{
  padding: 10px;
  text-align: left;
  vertical-align:middle;
  font-weight: 300;
  font-size: 12px;
  color: #fff;

}

tr:nth-child(odd) td {
  background:#2cc3ce;
  color:#0d3852;
}

/* demo styles */

@import url(http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:400,500,300,700);
body{
  background: #0d3852;
  font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
}
section{
  margin: 50px;
}

input {
    max-width:50px;
    text-align: left;
    border: 1px solid #aaa;
    background-color: #fff;
    padding: 5px 20px 5px 5px;
    margin-top: 1px;
    font-size: 13px;
}

*,
*:after,
*::before {
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

.ac-custom {
 padding: 0 1em;
 max-width: 900px;
 margin: 0 auto;
}

.ac-custom h2 {
 font-size: 1em;
 font-weight: 300;
 padding: 0 0 0.5em;
 margin: 0 0 30px;
 color:#0d3852;
}

.ac-custom ul,
.ac-custom ol {
 list-style: none;
 padding: 0;
 margin: 0 auto;
 max-width: 800px;
}

.ac-custom li {
 margin: 0 auto;
 /*padding: 0.5em 0;*/
 position: relative;
}

.ac-custom label {
 display: inline-block;
 position: relative;
 font-size: 1em;
 padding: 0 0 0 80px;
 vertical-align: top;
 color: #0d3852;
 cursor: pointer;
 -webkit-transition: color 0.3s;
 transition: color 0.3s;
}

/*
.ac-custom input[type="checkbox"],
.ac-custom input[type="radio"],
.ac-custom label::before {
 width: 20px;
 height: 20px;
 top: 50%;
 left: 0;
 margin-top: -12px;
 position: absolute;
 cursor: pointer;
}*/

.ac-custom input[type="checkbox"],
.ac-custom input[type="radio"] {
 opacity: 0;
 -webkit-appearance: none;
 display: inline-block;
 vertical-align: middle;
 z-index: 100;
}

/*
.ac-custom label::before {
 content: '';
 border: 1px solid #0d3852;
 -webkit-transition: opacity 0.3s;
 transition: opacity 0.3s;
}*/

.ac-radio label::before {
 border-radius: 50%;
}

.ac-custom input[type="checkbox"]:checked + label,
.ac-custom input[type="radio"]:checked + label {
 color: #fff;
} 

.ac-custom input[type="checkbox"]:checked + label::before,
.ac-custom input[type="radio"]:checked + label::before {
 opacity: 0.8;
}

/* General SVG and path styles */

.ac-custom svg {
 position: absolute;
 width: 20px;
 height: 20px;
 top: 50%;
 margin-top: -12px;
 left: 0px;
 pointer-events: none;
}

.ac-custom svg path {
 stroke: #0d3852;
 stroke-width: 13px;
 stroke-linecap: round;
 stroke-linejoin: round;
 fill: none;
}

/* Specific input, SVG and path styles */

/* Circle */
.ac-circle input[type="checkbox"],
.ac-circle input[type="radio"],
.ac-circle label::before {
 width: 30px;
 height: 30px;
 margin-top: -15px;
 left: 10px;
 position: absolute;
}

.ac-circle label::before {
 background-color: #fff;
 border: none;
}

.ac-circle svg {
 width: 70px;
 height: 70px;
 margin-top: -35px;
 left: -10px;
}

.ac-circle svg path {
 stroke-width: 5px;
} 

/* Box Fill */
.ac-boxfill svg path {
 stroke-width: 8px;
} 

/* Swirl */
.ac-swirl svg path {
 stroke-width: 8px;
}

/* List */
.ac-list ol {
 list-style: decimal;
 list-style-position: inside;
}

.ac-list ol li {
 font-size: 2em;
 padding: 1em 1em 0 2em;
 text-indent: -40px;
}

.ac-list ol li label {
 font-size: 0.5em;
 text-indent: 0;
 padding-left: 30px;
}

.ac-list label::before {
 display: none;
}

.ac-list svg {
 width: 100%;
 height: 80px;
 left: 0;
 top: 1.2em;
 margin-top: 0px;
}

.ac-list svg path {
 stroke-width: 4px;
}

.row {
  margin-left: -15px;
  margin-right: -15px;
  margin-top:0;
}
.col-sm-4 {
  position: relative;
  min-height: 1px;
  padding-left: 15px;
  padding-right: 15px;
  padding-bottom: 30px;
}

@media (min-width: 768px) {
  .col-sm-4 {
    float: left;
  }

  .col-sm-4 {
    width: 33.33333333%;
  } 
 
 .filter-columns {
 background-color:#2cc3ce;
 }
 
 .filter-columns-alt {
 background-color:#78D9E0;
 min-height:256px;
 }

ul,li { 
 margin:0; 
 padding:0; 
 list-style:none;
}

.label {
  color:#000;
  font-size:16px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.4/jquery.min.js"></script>

    <div id="body">


        <table>
            <thead>
                <tr id="ProductID" class="first">
                    <th>NAME</th>
                    <th>BET</th>
                    <th>BOOKIE</th>
                    <th>ODDS</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody></tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
```

As you can see, in this part of the JSON :

```
"outcomes" : [{ "name" : "No goal", "bookie" : "stoiximan", "odds" : 1.91, "stakes" : 53.5279805353 }, { "name" : "Goal", "bookie" : "betrebels", "odds" : 2.2, "stakes" : 46.4720194647 }]
```

it shows data from the last row (betrebels,2.2) but it misses the first row (stoiximan,1.91)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    //It loads the data from the JSON file 
    $(function() {
      
        var data = [{ "name" : "Άντερλεχτ - Σιντ Τρούιντεν(GG/NG)", "outcomes" : [{ "name" : "No goal", "bookie" : "stoiximan", "odds" : 1.91, "stakes" : 53.5279805353 }, { "name" : "Goal", "bookie" : "betrebels", "odds" : 2.2, "stakes" : 46.4720194647 }], "profit" : 2.23844282238 },
        { "name" : "Παρί Σεν Ζερμέν - Μπαρτσελόνα", "outcomes" : [{ "name" : "Παρί Σεν Ζερμέν (1)", "bookie" : "interwetten", "odds" : 4.1, "stakes" : 24.7827486321 }, { "name" : "X", "bookie" : "interwetten", "odds" : 3.5, "stakes" : 29.0312198262 }, { "name" : "Μπαρτσελόνα (2)", "bookie" : "betrebels", "odds" : 2.2, "stakes" : 46.1860315417 }], "profit" : 1.6092693917 }
    ];
      
     var tr;
  $.each(data, function(key, val) {
  dlen = val.outcomes.length;
 
 for(i = 0; i < dlen; i++ ){
      tr = $('<tr/>');
        tr.append('<td class="name" rel="' + val.name + '">' + val.name + '</td>');
        tr.append('<td class="bet" rel="' + val.outcomes[i].name + '">' + val.outcomes[i].name + '</td>');
        tr.append('<td class="bookie" rel="' + val.outcomes[i].bookie + '">' + val.outcomes[i].bookie + '</td>');
        tr.append('<td class="metric2" >' + val.outcomes[i].odds + '</td>');
        $('table').append(tr);
 }

    // $('table').append(tr);
  });


    });
    h1{
      font-size: 30px;
      color: #fff;
      text-transform: uppercase;
      font-weight: 300;
      text-align: center;
      margin-bottom: 15px;
    }
    table{
      width:100%;
      table-layout: fixed;
    }
    .tbl-header{
      background-color: rgba(255,255,255,0.3);
     }
    .tbl-content{
      height:300px;
      overflow-x:auto;
      margin-top: 0px;
    }

    th{
      padding: 20px 15px;
      text-align: left;
      font-weight: 500;
      font-size: 12px;
      color: #fff;
      text-transform: uppercase;
    }
    td{
      padding: 10px;
      text-align: left;
      vertical-align:middle;
      font-weight: 300;
      font-size: 12px;
      color: #fff;

    }

    tr:nth-child(odd) td {
      background:#2cc3ce;
      color:#0d3852;
    }

    /* demo styles */

    @import url(http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:400,500,300,700);
    body{
      background: #0d3852;
      font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
    }
    section{
      margin: 50px;
    }

    input {
        max-width:50px;
        text-align: left;
        border: 1px solid #aaa;
        background-color: #fff;
        padding: 5px 20px 5px 5px;
        margin-top: 1px;
        font-size: 13px;
    }

    *,
    *:after,
    *::before {
        -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
        -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
        box-sizing: border-box;
    }

    .ac-custom {
     padding: 0 1em;
     max-width: 900px;
     margin: 0 auto;
    }

    .ac-custom h2 {
     font-size: 1em;
     font-weight: 300;
     padding: 0 0 0.5em;
     margin: 0 0 30px;
     color:#0d3852;
    }

    .ac-custom ul,
    .ac-custom ol {
     list-style: none;
     padding: 0;
     margin: 0 auto;
     max-width: 800px;
    }

    .ac-custom li {
     margin: 0 auto;
     /*padding: 0.5em 0;*/
     position: relative;
    }

    .ac-custom label {
     display: inline-block;
     position: relative;
     font-size: 1em;
     padding: 0 0 0 80px;
     vertical-align: top;
     color: #0d3852;
     cursor: pointer;
     -webkit-transition: color 0.3s;
     transition: color 0.3s;
    }

    /*
    .ac-custom input[type="checkbox"],
    .ac-custom input[type="radio"],
    .ac-custom label::before {
     width: 20px;
     height: 20px;
     top: 50%;
     left: 0;
     margin-top: -12px;
     position: absolute;
     cursor: pointer;
    }*/

    .ac-custom input[type="checkbox"],
    .ac-custom input[type="radio"] {
     opacity: 0;
     -webkit-appearance: none;
     display: inline-block;
     vertical-align: middle;
     z-index: 100;
    }

    /*
    .ac-custom label::before {
     content: '';
     border: 1px solid #0d3852;
     -webkit-transition: opacity 0.3s;
     transition: opacity 0.3s;
    }*/

    .ac-radio label::before {
     border-radius: 50%;
    }

    .ac-custom input[type="checkbox"]:checked + label,
    .ac-custom input[type="radio"]:checked + label {
     color: #fff;
    } 

    .ac-custom input[type="checkbox"]:checked + label::before,
    .ac-custom input[type="radio"]:checked + label::before {
     opacity: 0.8;
    }

    /* General SVG and path styles */

    .ac-custom svg {
     position: absolute;
     width: 20px;
     height: 20px;
     top: 50%;
     margin-top: -12px;
     left: 0px;
     pointer-events: none;
    }

    .ac-custom svg path {
     stroke: #0d3852;
     stroke-width: 13px;
     stroke-linecap: round;
     stroke-linejoin: round;
     fill: none;
    }

    /* Specific input, SVG and path styles */

    /* Circle */
    .ac-circle input[type="checkbox"],
    .ac-circle input[type="radio"],
    .ac-circle label::before {
     width: 30px;
     height: 30px;
     margin-top: -15px;
     left: 10px;
     position: absolute;
    }

    .ac-circle label::before {
     background-color: #fff;
     border: none;
    }

    .ac-circle svg {
     width: 70px;
     height: 70px;
     margin-top: -35px;
     left: -10px;
    }

    .ac-circle svg path {
     stroke-width: 5px;
    } 

    /* Box Fill */
    .ac-boxfill svg path {
     stroke-width: 8px;
    } 

    /* Swirl */
    .ac-swirl svg path {
     stroke-width: 8px;
    }

    /* List */
    .ac-list ol {
     list-style: decimal;
     list-style-position: inside;
    }

    .ac-list ol li {
     font-size: 2em;
     padding: 1em 1em 0 2em;
     text-indent: -40px;
    }

    .ac-list ol li label {
     font-size: 0.5em;
     text-indent: 0;
     padding-left: 30px;
    }

    .ac-list label::before {
     display: none;
    }

    .ac-list svg {
     width: 100%;
     height: 80px;
     left: 0;
     top: 1.2em;
     margin-top: 0px;
    }

    .ac-list svg path {
     stroke-width: 4px;
    }

    .row {
      margin-left: -15px;
      margin-right: -15px;
      margin-top:0;
    }
    .col-sm-4 {
      position: relative;
      min-height: 1px;
      padding-left: 15px;
      padding-right: 15px;
      padding-bottom: 30px;
    }

    @media (min-width: 768px) {
      .col-sm-4 {
        float: left;
      }

      .col-sm-4 {
        width: 33.33333333%;
      } 
     
     .filter-columns {
     background-color:#2cc3ce;
     }
     
     .filter-columns-alt {
     background-color:#78D9E0;
     min-height:256px;
     }

    ul,li { 
     margin:0; 
     padding:0; 
     list-style:none;
    }

    .label {
      color:#000;
      font-size:16px;
    }
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.4/jquery.min.js"></script>

        <div id="body">


            <table>
                <thead>
                    <tr id="ProductID" class="first">
                        <th>NAME</th>
                        <th>BET</th>
                        <th>BOOKIE</th>
                        <th>ODDS</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody></tbody>
            </table>
        </div>
```

Comment: i realized that the your positioning of this snippet  `$('table').append(tr);` was causing some values to be overwritten.... so i moved it into the third loop to fix the issue.

Comment: I moved that too and it worked. But in some cases there are three nests and not two. And it misses out the last one (in case there are 3).

Comment: fixing in a few

Comment: When you update the snippet, let me know please. I have not managed to alter my code and make it work.

Comment: It works. But for a reason it messes up with some queries I had before. This works : apolosiskos.co.uk/TEB/TEST/ but this does not : http://apolosiskos.co.uk/TEB/JSON2/2/